# Nested select in mysql v 3.23

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

I want write this sql select statment in mysql v 3.23

```
select * 
    from radacct 
    where username in ( 
        select username 
            from radcheck 
            where Attribute = 'max-weekly-session'
    );
```

but say

```
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax near 
'select username from radcheck where Attribute= 'max-weekly-session')' 
at line 1
```

in mysql v 5 this is ok but how can I do in v 3.23?

Comment: Do you really still need to support 3.23?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nested selects are not available in MySQL version < 4.1

following will work

```
select radacct.* 
from radacct inner join radcheck on radacct.username = radcheck.username 
where radcheck.Attribute= 'max-weekly-session'
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select a.* 
from radacct a 
join radcheck b on a.username = b.username
where b.Attribute = 'max-weekly-session'
```

Answer (score 1):

Full standards-compliant support for subqueries [was added in 4.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/subqueries.html). Prior to that, you had to use JOINs and other workarounds to achieve the same effect.

See [12.2.8.11. Rewriting Subqueries as Joins for Earlier MySQL Versions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/rewriting-subqueries.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from radacct ra
inner join radcheck on ra.username = rc.username
where rc.Attribute = 'max-weekly-session'
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar but all solutions given here cause a bug were multiple entries are returned from radacct. I've fixed this by adding a `group by` on the radacct key.

```
select ra.* 
from radacct ra
inner join radcheck rc on ra.username = rc.username
where rc.Attribute = 'max-weekly-session'
group by ra.Id
```